# Avoid wasting space when placing multiple aligned plots onto one page

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to place four plots onto a single page. Axis labels should be printed only at the very rim, i.e. *x* axis labels for the bottom diagrams only, and *y* axis labels for the left diagrams only. This goes both for the name of the axis as a whole and the individual tick marks. I can generate something along these lines using the following code:

```
pdf(file = "ExampleOutput.pdf",
    width = 6.61,
    height = 6.61,
    pointsize = 10
    )
set.seed(42)
catA <- factor(c("m100", "m500", "m1000", "m2000", "m3000", "m5000"))
catB <- factor(20:28)
samples <- 100
rsample <- function(v) v[ceiling(runif(samples, max=length(v)))]
Tab <- data.frame(catA = rsample(catA),
                  catB = rsample(catB),
                  valA = rnorm(samples, 150, 8),
                  valB = pmin(1,pmax(0,rnorm(samples, 0.5, 0.3))))
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for (i in 0:3) {
  x <- Tab[[1 + i %% 2]]
  plot(x, Tab[[3 + i %/% 2]],
       xlab = if (i %/% 2 == 1) "Some Categories" else NULL,
       ylab = if (i %% 2 == 0) "Some Values" else NULL,
       axes = FALSE
       )
  axis(side = 1,
       at=1:nlevels(x),
       labels = if (i %/% 2 == 1) levels(x) else FALSE)
  axis(side = 2, labels = (i %% 2 == 0))
  box(which = "plot", bty = "l")
}
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
dev.off()
```

I'll welcome suggestions for how to improve my ploting commands, perhaps avoid draing the axes and the L in the lower left corner manually. But that's only a besides.

The result of this sequence looks like this:

[image: Current output]

The problem here is the *huge* amount of wasted whitespace. I have the impression that R reserves space for axis and tick labels even if they are not used. As a consequence of this wasted space, for the left bottom diagram, only every second *x* tick actually gets labeled, which is really bad here.

I'd like to generate a similar plot without that much white space. The actual plots should be the same size, so they line up properly, but the space for the labels should be only at the outside. I imagine a layout like this (mockup created in GIMP):

[image: Desired output]

How can I achieve such a layout?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Here is a slight modification of the general plot you show, assuming that the y and x axis labels pertain to all plots. It uses an outer margin to contain the axis labelling, which we add with `title()` using argument `outer = TRUE`. The effect is somewhat like the labelling in **ggplot2** or **lattice** plots.

The key line here is:

```
op <- par(mfrow = c(2,2),
          oma = c(5,4,0,0) + 0.1,
          mar = c(0,0,1,1) + 0.1)
```

which sets plot parameters (the values in place prior to the call are stored in `op`). We use `5` and `4` lines on sides 1 and 2 for the outer margin, which is the usual number for the `mar` parameter. Plot region margins (`mar`) of 1 line each are added to the top and right sides, to give a little room between plots.

The axis labels are added *after* the `for()` loop with

```
title(xlab = "Some Categories",
      ylab = "Some Values",
      outer = TRUE, line = 3)
```

The entire script is:

```
set.seed(42)
catA <- factor(c("m100", "m500", "m1000", "m2000", "m3000", "m5000"))
catB <- factor(20:28)
samples <- 100
rsample <- function(v) v[ceiling(runif(samples, max=length(v)))]
Tab <- data.frame(catA = rsample(catA),
                  catB = rsample(catB),
                  valA = rnorm(samples, 150, 8),
                  valB = pmin(1,pmax(0,rnorm(samples, 0.5, 0.3))))
op <- par(mfrow = c(2,2),
          oma = c(5,4,0,0) + 0.1,
          mar = c(0,0,1,1) + 0.1)
for (i in 0:3) {
  x <- Tab[[1 + i %% 2]]
  plot(x, Tab[[3 + i %/% 2]], axes = FALSE)
  axis(side = 1,
       at=1:nlevels(x),
       labels = if (i %/% 2 == 1) levels(x) else FALSE)
  axis(side = 2, labels = (i %% 2 == 0))
  box(which = "plot", bty = "l")
}
title(xlab = "Some Categories",
      ylab = "Some Values",
      outer = TRUE, line = 3)
par(op)
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: This is excellent, though it doesn't solve the OP's issue with the labels on the x-axis of the lower left plot. A smaller point size on the axis labels might allow those to squeeze in, but it may leave very small labels.

Comment: OK, my example was chosen badly: the axis labels need to be different for the two halves. Nevertheless, it's good to know that this approach does exist, and the illustration really adds value to the answer. And `oma` and `mar` seem to indicate a valuable direction in any case.

Comment: With the help of this answer, I got it working for me using `par(mfrow = c(2,2), oma = c(2, 2, 0, 0), mar = c(1, 1, 0, 0), mgp = c(2, 1, 0), xpd = NA)`. Feel free to include that in your answer as well, and thanks a lot!

Comment: @Glen_b I missed that specific point in the Answer; judicious use of `cex.axis` would solve that, as would rotating the labels with `las` and giving a bit more room on the bottom outer margin.

Answer (score 26):

Building heavily on [the answer from Gavin Simpson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13241088/1468366), I now use the following solution:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2),     # 2x2 layout
    oma = c(2, 2, 0, 0), # two rows of text at the outer left and bottom margin
    mar = c(1, 1, 0, 0), # space for one row of text at ticks and to separate plots
    mgp = c(2, 1, 0),    # axis label at 2 rows distance, tick labels at 1 row
    xpd = NA)            # allow content to protrude into outer margin (and beyond)
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Resulting image]

As you can see, this is enough to allow printing of all the tick labels as well. If it were not, then according to [Gavin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239986/avoid-wasting-space-when-placing-multiple-aligned-plots-onto-one-page#comment18051272_13241088), adding `cex.axis` with a value smaller than 1 to the parameter list should help reduce the font size there.

Answer (score 19):

Just manipulate your parameters, in `par`. The argument `mar` controls margin size for individual plot. Change your `par` to this:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2), mar=c(1, 4, 1, 1) + 0.1)#it goes c(bottom, left, top, right)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a conditional evaluation that assigns to `par('mar')` values that are appropriate to the positioning; Here is an example of code (inside your loop)  that checks for the "x-layout-position":

```
    pdf(file = "ExampleOutput2.pdf",
    width = 6.61,
    height = 6.61,
    pointsize = 10
    )
set.seed(42)
catA <- factor(c("m100", "m500", "m1000", "m2000", "m3000", "m5000"))
catB <- factor(20:28)
samples <- 100
rsample <- function(v) v[ceiling(runif(samples, max=length(v)))]
Tab <- data.frame(catA = rsample(catA),
                  catB = rsample(catB),
                  valA = rnorm(samples, 150, 8),
                  valB = pmin(1,pmax(0,rnorm(samples, 0.5, 0.3))))
par(mfrow = c(2,2), mar= c(3, 4, 1, 1) + 0.1)
for (i in 0:3) {
  x <- Tab[[1 + i %% 2]]
  plot(x, Tab[[3 + i %/% 2]], mar= if(i %/%2 == 0) {c(4, 4, 1, 1) + 0.1 
                                              }else{c(1, 1, 1, 1) + 0.1},
       xlab = if (i %/% 2 == 1) "Some Categories" else NULL,
       ylab = if (i %% 2 == 0) "Some Values" else NULL,
       axes = FALSE
       )
  axis(side = 1,
       at=1:nlevels(x),
       labels = if (i %/% 2 == 1) levels(x) else FALSE)
  axis(side = 2, labels = (i %% 2 == 0))
  box(which = "plot", bty = "l")
}
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
dev.off()
```

You will need to adjust this to suit you needs, since it only handles two margin conditions andy you really have 4 separate conditions (2 below  both needing more bottom-space, with the right one needing less left-space and two above (also with different requirements) . If you shrink the 'mar' value globally it will cut off your x and y labels as can be seen in the loss of the xlab values when you only drop this code into your loop.

Comment: I tried this out, and I can't see any difference in the result. Could it be that the per-plot settings don't apply to the positioning of multiple plots on a single page? Or is there some other reason that might suppress an effect for this? Can you actually make this work in my code?

Comment: It was working in your code. But Gavin's answer looks better anyway.

Comment: Very strange, that this works for you but not for me. If I had any more time, I might want to investigate this further, particularly since your solution might be more flexible for other layouts (e.g. 3x3 with *some* inner axes labeled as well). But I won't track this down today. For reference: I tried this with R 2.15.2 and using the pdf output driver as indicated in my code.

Comment: OK, I'll post the full code that worked on a Mac 10.6.8 with R 2.15.2