# Resize margins between different plots in one graph

Tags: r, plot, margins

I want to plot those 3 plots into one graph using the layout command below.
Unfortunately the margins between plot 1 and 2 are quite big. I already tried the "heights=c()" command but I don't want to change the proportion between both plots. I would love to have the same size for both plots, therefore just decrease the margin between, but I haven't found an adequate solution yet and I am not sure how to use the par(mar) command in here.

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,3,2,2,3),2,3,byrow=TRUE))
hist(Data$X,breaks=16,prob=TRUE,xlab="X",ylab="Density",main="",ylim=c(0.000,0.040))
axis(side=1,at=seq(40,120,10),labels=seq(40,120,10))
lines(density(Data$X,na.rm=TRUE), col="blue", lwd=2)
lines(density(Data$X,na.rm=TRUE, adjust=2),lty="dotted",col="darkgreen", lwd=2)
qqnorm(Data$X,main="")
boxplot(Data$X)
```

Thank you very much for your assistance. Is there a possibility to use ggplot with aes() instead?

Thanks a lot!

Thore

Comment: I can't reproduce your code, start to try `?par` and have a look at the `mar` parameter.

Comment: I think this is effectively a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239986/avoid-wasting-space-when-placing-multiple-aligned-plots-onto-one-page.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the excess whitespace is entirely caused by the combination of top and bottom margins between the under and over figures. From playing around with `mar`, it looks to me like you can fix this just by decreasing both the top and bottom margins from their default of `c(5,4,4,2)+0.1` to `c(4,4,1,1)+0.1` (note: I also decreased the right margin slightly for evenness) (note: since you didn't provide your `Data`, I synthesized it from a normal distribution):

```
set.seed(1); Data <- data.frame(X=rnorm(100,80,15))
par(mar=c(4,4,1,1)+0.1)

layout(matrix(c(1,1,3,2,2,3),2,3,byrow=TRUE))
hist(Data$X,breaks=16,prob=TRUE,xlab="X",ylab="Density",main="",ylim=c(0.000,0.040))
axis(side=1,at=seq(40,120,10),labels=seq(40,120,10))
lines(density(Data$X,na.rm=TRUE), col="blue", lwd=2)
lines(density(Data$X,na.rm=TRUE, adjust=2),lty="dotted",col="darkgreen", lwd=2)
qqnorm(Data$X,main="")
boxplot(Data$X)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you. The excessive margins resulted from a 'hidden x labelling', after setting the upper-margins for the lower plot to another value (4) and deleting the x label from the first plot completely it worked. I don't knoe how this label dissappeared but thank you anyways.